# PHP - Session Cookies are expiring/invalidating earlier then expected

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, cookies

I go and login using the following script

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $query[0]['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $query[0]['image'];
$_SESSION['role'] = $query[0]['role'];
$_SESSION['banned'] = $query[0]['banned'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $query[0]['id'];
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['useragent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+604800,"/");
//redirect to homepage since now logged in.
```

Now im at the homepage again and logged in, Everything works as it should.
But after only a few hours, isset($_SESSION['username']) will return false, yet the expiry time is still set to 7 days, and the cookie is still there.

The hour of the expiry date is 1 hour behind my timezone's actual time hour. Not sure if this matters. I changed the timezone serverside to a random timezone and the cookie expire data didn't change.

.htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 604800
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800
```

(This htaccess is in root, and the first block of code above, was in root/login. Not sure if it matters).

Comment: Your pc time is 18:52 GMT

Comment: @craig correct.

Comment: set timezone and try again - date_default_timezone_set('Your time zone');

Comment: @craig What good would setting a timezone do? Theres really no need for that.

Comment: **Im still getting this issue - anymore help would be great**

Answer (score 0):

Move your `session_start();` and `session_regenerate_id();` to the bottom of the script.

```
<?php
$_SESSION['username'] = $query[0]['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION['image'] = $query[0]['image'];
$_SESSION['role'] = $query[0]['role'];
$_SESSION['banned'] = $query[0]['banned'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $query[0]['id'];
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$_SESSION['useragent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+604800,"/");
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
?>
```

Reason behind this logic is that you are setting the cookies, and once they are set and ready, then you start the session. There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878633/1527252) that explains it better:

1. Cookie data is sent in the header of the page.
2. You can not set cookies after you have sent the headers to the client.
3. Headers will be sent as soon as you start outputting any data to the client (ie: the browser).

Comment: Can you explain what this does exactly? As in whats the difference?

Comment: Ok, I usually run session_start(); on all pages that I require to grab for ex, username or image. Should I not be doing that? If I leave that out, it doesnt actually show up at all. Also doesnt regenerate id, basically delete the old and grab a new session cookie etc?

Comment: You need `session_start()` wherever you're using the user data; you just have to create the values of the cookies before sending the headers. If you are not setting new cookies just use `session_start`

Comment: Any information for cookies or headers that you needed stored in the session have to be created before they are sent out

Comment: Alright - well it seems session_regenerate_id may not be needed here, not sure why I was using it tbh. And putting session_start after I set the session vars make no sense as the session_start doesnt recognize them and wont set them. I have even tried it and all it does is make the cookie with no variable data.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worst trying to use built-in [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), instead of doing a hack to change the cookie's expiration date... Also note that `session_regenerate_id` can cause [sessions being lost](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).

Comment: yeah seems I dont need session_regenerate_id, I have removed it and everything is working as it should. No idea why I had it and not sure if this has fixed it or not.